# MySql Insert substrings from another table with CASE

Tags: mysql, insert, case, conditional-statements

I try to split a value from another table into several columns in another table with a condition. 
As an example i have 2 tables:

**rawdataTbl**:

Id int

a varchar

**detailedTbl**

Id int

b varchar

c varchar

d varchar

I tried the following:

```
INSERT INTO detailedTbl
SELECT
CASE 
WHEN a LIKE "%someText%"
  "Something",
  substr(a, 1, 5),
  substr(a, 6, 8)
WHEN a LIKE "%someText2%"
  "Something else",
  substr(a, 4, 5),
  substr(a, 7, 9)
END
FROM rawdataTbl;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
INSERT INTO detailedTbl
(b,c,d)
SELECT
CASE 
    WHEN a LIKE "%someText%" THEN "Something"
    WHEN a LIKE "%someText2%" THEN "Something else"
END,
CASE 
    WHEN a LIKE "%someText%" THEN substr(a, 1, 5)
    WHEN a LIKE "%someText2%" THEN substr(a, 6, 8)
END,
CASE 
    WHEN a LIKE "%someText%" THEN substr(a, 4, 5)
    WHEN a LIKE "%someText2%" THEN substr(a, 7, 9)
END
FROM rawdataTbl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably most flexible to use UNION with several queries each with their own WHERE clause:-

```
INSERT INTO detailedTbl
SELECT "Something",
      substr(a, 1, 5),
      substr(a, 6, 8)

FROM rawdataTbl
WHERE a LIKE "%someText%"
UNION
SELECT "Something else",
      substr(a, 4, 5),
      substr(a, 7, 9)
FROM rawdataTbl
WHERE a LIKE "%someText2%";
```

This isn't directly comparable as it could insert 2 rows if the value being checked matched against 2 of the LIKE clauses. If this causes a problem then you need to return the columns separately in your original query:-

```
INSERT INTO detailedTbl
SELECT
CASE 
    WHEN a LIKE "%someText%"
      "Something",
    WHEN a LIKE "%someText2%"
      "Something else",
END,
CASE 
    WHEN a LIKE "%someText%"
      substr(a, 1, 5),
    WHEN a LIKE "%someText2%"
      substr(a, 4, 5),
END,
CASE 
    WHEN a LIKE "%someText%"
      substr(a, 6, 8)
    WHEN a LIKE "%someText2%"
      substr(a, 7, 9)
END
FROM rawdataTbl;
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! The second one worked, I just had to add "THEN" after every WHEN ...